# Lottery Ball Question

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I came across a lottery problem for the class I am TAing and I am a little confused as to how to solve it.

The problem is as follows: To play the Lottery, you select 6 numbers between 1 and 59. The lottery draws 6 winning numbers and a bonus number (all from the same 59 balls).

The prizes are as follows:

1st prize: Hit all 6 winning numbers.
2nd prize: Hit 5 winning numbers + Bonus.
3rd prize: Hit 5 winning numbers (no bonus).
4th prize: Hit 4 winning numbers (no bonus).
5th prize: Hit 3 winning numbers (no bonus).

I am trying to calculate the odds of winning each prize. For 1st prize, I am pretty sure its 1 in $\binom{59}{6}$

For second prize, I think it is $\binom{6}{5}$ out of $\binom{59}{6}$ for hitting the 5 winners, but what about the bonus? Do I multiply that by $1/59$ for the chance of getting the bonus? Or is it something different?

Comment: You: _4th prize: Hit 4 winning numbers (no bonus)._ I take it that if you hit 4 winning numbers, they are not going to "punish" you for also hitting the bonus number? I mean is "4 winning numbers, 1 bonus number, and 1 wrong number" a ***4th prize*** or ***no prize***? Same with 5th prize of course.

Comment: I believe 4th prize means to get exactly 4 winning numbers and two losing numbers, no bonus. Similarly for the others.

Comment: In a realistic lottery, people will demand that 4 winning, 1 bonus, and 1 losing number be _at least_ as valuable as 4 winning, 0 bonus, and 2 losing numbers.

Comment: This is a question from a textbook, not a realistic lottery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine 59 balls; one labelled *B* for "bonus", six labelled *W* for "winners", and fifty two labelled *L* for "losers". When you randomly draw 6 balls, the chance of getting $b$ bonuses, $w$ winners, and $l$ losers with $b+w+l=6$ is $$\displaystyle {{1\choose b}{6\choose w}{52\choose l}}\over \displaystyle{59\choose 6}.$$

For the first prize, $b=0,w=6,l=0$ and the probability is $1/{59\choose 6}$, as you said.

For the second prize, $b=1,w=5,l=0$ and the probability is $6/{59\choose 6}$, you don't need to multiply by anything else.

For the third prize, $b=0,w=5,l=1$ and the probability is $(6\cdot 52)/{59\choose 6}$.

Comment: That makes a heck of a lot of sense. I was thinking about it a different way for some reason. So really you pretend to draw the numbers first, and then see how many possible matching tickets you can make. Excellent answer!

Comment: I'm glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

You are correct for the first.  For the second, there are ${59 \choose 6}53$ possible draws, as there are only $53$ numbers left for the bonus.  You succeed in ${6 \choose 5}$ of those.  Note this is less likely than first prize.  For third, the number of draws again cares about the bonus, but you succeed ${6 \choose 5}52$ ways, as you can pick any five of the winning numbers plus a non-bonus.

Comment: I can't agree that the second prize is less likely. You succeed in your way of counting in ${6 \choose 5}\cdot 53$ ways for the second prize. This is because there's one "main" ball that you miss, and it may be located in 53 different positions.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen:  But you need to get the bonus ball for second prize.

Comment: They still draw 6 winning balls and 1 bonus ball. You have only 6 numbers on your ticket. So you need 1 out of 1 on the bonus ball, combined with just 5 out of 6 on the winning balls. That's easier than 6 out of 6 winning balls. Do you disagree with the probabilities of the other answer?

Answer (score 0):

There are ${59 \choose 6}$ possible ways to select 6 numbers between 1 and 59. For the first prize you have to hit all 6 numbers out of 6: ${6 \choose 6} \over {59 \choose 6}$.

For the second prize you have to hit 5 numbers out of 6 and 1 "bonus" number out of 1: ${6 \choose 5} \cdot {1 \choose 1} \over {59 \choose 6}$.

For the third prize you have to hit 5 numbers out of 6 and 1 number from the "losers" excluding "bonus" which is 59 - 6 - 1 = 52, therefore the probability is ${6 \choose 5} \cdot {52 \choose 1} \over {59 \choose 6}$.

Note that without "bonus" there are ${6 \choose 5} \cdot {53 \choose 1} = 6\cdot 53=318$ ways to choose 5 "winners" out of 6 and 1 "looser" out of remaining 53 which is equal to ${6 \choose 5} \cdot {1 \choose 1} + {6 \choose 5} \cdot {52 \choose 1} = 6 + 312 =318$ and means that by drawing a "bonus" number the organizers are selecting 6 out of 318 "hit 5" sequences and giving them the second prize. The remaining 312 "hit 5 no bonus" are getting the third prize.

For the fourth and the fifth prizes we assume that organizers are not going to punish for choosing the "bonus" number, so there are 53 "losers" and the probabilities are ${6 \choose 4} \cdot {53 \choose 2} \over {59 \choose 6}$ and ${6 \choose 3} \cdot {53 \choose 3} \over {59 \choose 6}$ respectively.

Actually, with numbers choice between 1 and 43 this lottery is realistic and known as the Loto 6 in Japan.